# Typescript: type coercion when computed property

Tags: typescript

Typescript version: 4.2.3

I want to make union's values as object literal type's key like below:

```
type Values = "888" | "123"
type Something = {
  [key in Values] : number
}
```

So that I can access object value like `something["888"]`.

But the result is not what I want:

```
// What I want:
// property are **string** type
type Something = {
  "888": string;
  "123": string;
}

// But the real result is:
// property became **number** type. 
type Something = {
  888: string;
  123: string;
}
```

I can't figure out why this happen ?
And is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties are *always* strings. It's working as intended.

Let's add something that could not be coerced to a number:

```
type Values = "888" | "123" | "asdf"
type Something = {
  [key in Values] : number
}
```

Now if you mouse over `Something` you should see:

```
type Something = {
    888: number;
    123: number;
    asdf: number;
}
```

In the popup of the type, it shows the properties without quotes because that is the syntax as an object literal would use.

For example:

```
const foo: Something = {
  888: 123,
  123: 456,
  asdf: 789,
}
const foo888 = foo["888"]
```

Here the object `foo` has properties of names `"888"`, `"123"` and `"asdf"`.

---

In plain javascript objects *always* store their property names as strings. But coercion to numbers is allowed. Typescript lets you do the same:

```
// both work fine
const foo888string = foo["888"]
const foo888number = foo[888]
```

Comment: So the object properties are always string. The popup message, IDE's hint,  is just syntax makes that object literal. It doesn't mean the real type.

Comment: It is the real type because object keys are _always_ strings. `Object.keys({ 888: 123 })` returns `["888"]`

Comment: Thanks. I think I learn something from your answer.